# Country specific domain with duplicate content on an international domain

Tags: duplicate-content, top-level-domains, cctld

I have a site that is currently hosted at a ccTLD (`.co.uk`). The audience for this site is international but largely based in the UK. I would like to keep the ccTLD for a UK audience as it has brand recognition and an easy to remember domain.

Is it possible to host the site (a full duplicate) at another TLD for international users while still keeping the ccTLD for UK users without appearing as duplicate content to search engines?

Just to be clear, the content isn't localised; The only difference is the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting one domain into plenty is not good and not required. ccTLD and TLD domains do not religiously set the intended audience, in fact you can use any TLD, or ccTLD regardless of the extension to target any country you want.

TLD and ccTLD have never and are not sole indicators where the server is located or what audience is targeted.

If you want to target the UK audience as a primary and the US audience as the secondary then its very likely you have told Google Webmaster Tools your intended audience. Selecting UK audience doesn't mean you won't get audience from the US.